# Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Color' which excludes null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have upgrade flutter version to 2.0.4, when I run the project(**this project was runing on old flutter version**)it throws warning because of package I used.

this is the package that I used : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker

and this is the error:

```
../../../flutter2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:311:32: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Color' which excludes null.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
                  color: theme.backgroundColor ?? Colors.white,
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning, not an error.  It simply means that `?? Colors.white` is unnecessary, since `theme.backgroundColor` will never be null.  Aside from an annoying message every time you use `flutter run`, this should not negatively affect your app.

According to the library's issue tracker, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/issues/235) which has already been fixed, but that fix hasn't made it into any releases yet.